# how can I prevent user to go to login page after successful authentication?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, django-authentication, django-registration

I am adding settings.py, root url and views.py. After login user is redirected to respective dashboard. In this situation, if user is pressing back button or changing url to accounts/login, then also it should remain on the dashboard page only. I am using django-registration-redux

settings.py

```
REGISTRATION_OPEN = True
ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7
REGISTRATION_AUTO_LOGIN = False
REGISTRATION_FORM = 'signin.forms.MyRegForm'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/signin/user_sign/'
```

views.py

```
def user_sign(request):
    obj = UserSelection.objects.get(user=request.user)

    if obj.user_type == 'candidate':
        return redirect('candidate:cand_dash')

    else:
        return redirect('employer:employer_dash')
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from signin.regbackend import MyRegistrationView
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='registration/login.html'), name='home'),
    url(r'^accounts/register/$', MyRegistrationView.as_view(), name='registration_register'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),

    url(r'^candidate/', include('candidate.urls')),
    url(r'^employer/', include('employer.urls')),
    url(r'^signin/', include('signin.urls')),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a Boolean variable `authenticated`.

Then you should need to set it as `False` before the user Authentication.

```
def registration(request):
    authenticated = False
...
```

Then after the user's authentication just change the var as `authenticated = True`

Finally every time you need to know if user is authenticated just use `if user.authenticated`

Also, if you need to use authenticated a lot take a look at custom decorators (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/decorators/) maybe they could help you.

Comment: Thanks for providing solution but I can not understand where to put those condition? I am using django-registration-redux. If you can give more specific details, please help.@Panos Angelopoulos

Comment: Please provide us with a detailed version of views.py file. @Kuntal

Comment: The views.py file I have mentioned above. After user is logging in, it is goint to that view. I have no other view for login purpose as I am using django-registration-redux package. @Panos Angelopoulos

Comment: You could put the code snippet below your `def user_sign(request)`. Also, you need to add user.authenticated = True. Before you implement this snippet extend your User model in your models.py file. You could easily do this process (https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html).

Finally, use an if statement like `if user.authenticated return redirect('dashboard') else return redirect('login')`.